# How to check if next line in text file is empty?

Tags: java, io

I want the program to find "[DesiredText]" and check if next line is empty, then if it is i want to take position of empty line. I saw few example but I doesn't work properly. All advices and clues are welcome.

```
BufferedReader br = new BufferedReader(new FileReader(file));

String line = null;

while ((line = br.readLine()) != null) {

 if ((line.contains("[DesiredText]") && br.readLine().isEmpty())) {

              RandomAccessFile raf = new RandomAccessFile("D:\\Temp.txt","r");
              long position = raf.getFilePointer();
              pozycje.add(position);
              raf.close();


        }
}
```

Comment: _I doesn't work properly_ How so?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Read the line, then check

```
   if("".equals(line))
```

Or if you don't want to count white-space:

```
   if("".equals(line.trim()))
```

Also, if you have a loop like `while ((line = br.readLine()) != null)` which is controlled by the value of `br.readLine()` you should *not* be calling `br.readLine()` again inside the loop.  That may cause you to go past the end of the file inside the loop and get an error.

What you should do, is set a flag when you find `line.contains("[DesiredText]")` and then in the next iteration of the loop (the next line) you will check if the line is empty if that flag is set.

Answer (score 0):

You could keep track of the length of the string+ newline char you have read so far, and once you get a blank line, the length variable should give you the position of the blank line.

Answer (score 0):

You can create two RandomAccessFiles where the second one will be one line further than first one. Something like:

```
    RandomAccessFile first = new RandomAccessFile("D:\\Temp.txt","r");
    RandomAccessFile second = new RandomAccessFile("D:\\Temp.txt","r");

    String line;
    String nextLine = second.readLine();

    while (nextLine != null) {
        line = first.readLine();
        nextLine = second.readLine();

        if ((line.contains("[DesiredText]") && nextLine.isEmpty())) {
            pozycje.add(first.getFilePointer());
        }
    }
```